# jQuery click not working for a second time clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to send the ajax, but the problem is when user clicks for a second time on the button it does not post to backend or do not submit data, for it to work again the user needs to reload the page again. Anyone has an idea why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_follow').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopPropagation();
        //$('#divId :input').serialize();
        var follow_and_unfollow = $("#user_page_follow :input").serialize();
        $.post(
            "backend/ajax/follow_and_unfollow.php",
            follow_and_unfollow
        ).done(function (data) {

            //$("#testimonials").load(location.href+" #testimonials>*","");
            $("#follow").html(data);
            $("#user_followers").load(location.href + " #user_followers>*", "");

        }).fail(function () {
            //alert("Error submitting forms!");
        });
    });
});
```

on second click on `#btn_follow` it's not submitting, the user needs to reload the page for it to work

Comment: do you get an error on your console when you click the event for the first time?

Comment: no, its working all fine and getting the html from the backend, just on second time click i need to reload the page to it works

Comment: i edited my question.

Comment: Could you post your HTML structure too? My best guess is that you're overwriting your HTML, and importantly the button, with the AJAX response and therefore the initial button element that had the click event bound is now gone.

Comment: PS. If that is the case, you can either use event delegation (e.g. binding the click event to a parent element that doesn't get replaced, [see here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)) or, wrap your click binding code in a function and after you overwrite the btn, re-run the binding function.

Comment: it's not my html error, it's getting the backend buttons all fine , the only problem is that click.function maybe is called only once because of document.load

Comment: Is `#btn_follow` inside of `#follow` or `#user_followers`?

Comment: yeah `#btn_follow` is inside of `#follow`

Comment: you think I should I add `$( "#btn_follow" ).append( "btn_follow_new" );` ?

Answer (score 1):

As we've confirmed in the comments, you're overwriting your original button with new content returned via AJAX. As such, the button element that you'd bound the click even too is gone, replaced with a new bit of HTML from the server.

I'd suggest you do the following. Replace:

```
$('#btn_follow').click(function (e) {
```

With:

```
$('#follow').on('click', '#btn_follow', function (e) {
```

This essentially binds the handler to the `#follow` element, but only runs it if the element clicked matches the filter expression. It's called event delegation and it's an important concept. Read about it [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: + 1 but problem stay the same, let me explain it better: `button#btn_follow` is generated via php when load the user page it checks user session if logged user is following the user page it will return a button with the `value="follow"` or `unfollow` , so button id stay the same, only values are changed, on click it send the ajax to the backend were check the value `follow or unfollow` and follow the user returning the follow and unfollow button with value to the page again.
 maybe I should add full code so you will understand it better

Comment: Definitely if you could add the HTML and simulate the process we'd be able to help more. Maybe a code fiddle?